# How to match two tables and insert it into another table in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I need to match two tables and insert it into the disbursment table, so this is my code...

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Approved Request
    $approvedRequest= DB::table('request')
    ->where('users_MemId',Auth::user()->MemId)
    ->where('requestStatus','Approved')
    ->join('requestdetails','request.requestId','=','requestdetails.request_requestId')
    ->join('itemattribute','requestdetails.RequestDetailsId','=','itemattribute.RequestDetailsId')
    ->join('exudeinventory', 'itemattribute.AttrName', '=', 'exudeinventory.ItemName')
    ->select('itemattribute.AttrName', 'exudeinventory.InventoryId', 'request.requestId')
    ->get();
    // dd($approvedRequest);
```

store function.

[image: store function]

I've tried matching the tables and I can't figure out on how to insert the values in another table or if I am doing it right.

[image: disbursment table]

[image: exudeinventory table]

[image: itemattribute table]

I've been looking for solutions but still I can't figure it out, Hope that someone would help me and explain it to me, I am new to laravel T,T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do this:

```
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //Approved Request
            $approvedRequest= DB::table('request')
            ->where('users_MemId',Auth::user()->MemId)
            ->where('requestStatus','Approved')
            ->join('requestdetails','request.requestId','=','requestdetails.request_requestId')
            ->join('itemattribute','requestdetails.RequestDetailsId','=','itemattribute.RequestDetailsId')
            ->join('exudeinventory', 'itemattribute.AttrName', '=', 'exudeinventory.ItemName')
            ->select('itemattribute.AttrName', 'exudeinventory.InventoryId', 'request.requestId')
            ->get()
            ->each (function ($request, $key) {
                $dis = new Disbursment;
                $dis->DisbursmentId = rand(1, 999999);
                $dis->ItemImage = 'default.jpg';
                $dis->ItemTypeId = $request->AttrName;
                $dis->exudeinventory_InventoryId = $request->InventoryId;
                $dis->request_requestId = $request->requestId;
                $dis->save();
            });
        }
```

Comment: how do you make the object random? is that possible? 'cause this one matches all the donations and its supposed to be 1 request = 1 donation.. @ako

Comment: @ShinaxMahiro I copied it from your codes. But it is not recommended to insert `primary key`'s value manually. Make it `AutoIncrement` in the database and it will get it's value automatically.